# Can we use Graph API delegated permission for Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-data-factory

I am trying to get *"/groups"* endpoint of **Microsoft Graph API** in my tenants via Azure Data Factory. I have given "Delegated permission" for my service principal. To my knowledge, when there is no user to act on behalf of, we should use "Application permission".

However, organization requirement does not allow me to use Application permission.

Therefore, when I try to execute my pipeline, I get "insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

Can this be the reason because ADF does not allow to use delegated permissions as there is no user to act on behalf of?

Comment: Do you receive the error "insufficient privileges to complete the operation" for user with delegated permissions or with application permissions?

Comment: @user2250152 for delegated.

Comment: @Fərid Qənbərli, can you please your token in jwt.ms and see what the permissions are available , here are the list of permissions required for groups: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

Comment: @MehtabSiddique for this case Applicatio Permission solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to get groups endpoint using graph api from ADF***
And got same error:
***`Insufficient privileges to complete the operation`***

[image]

Make sure you have Microsoft graph permissions to query groups and users.

[image]

The user here do not has **`Data Factory contributor`** role .

[image]

[image]

Or  make sure you  ADF has proper access to the resources .So give it **`contributor`** role

[image]

And if your are using storage account to store the rest response, make sure user , app or group has **`Storage blob data contributor`** role.

**Reference:**

[Copy and transform data from and to a REST endpoint - Azure Data Factory & Azure Synapse | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#dataset-properties)